# Automatically including more packages

Tags: packages

I use latex a lot for academic purposes (usually sharelatex and more recently, overleaf v2), because of that I always need some math or physics related packages like amsmath, siunitix and a lot of other ones. Because of that, it would be very practical for me if it was possible to configure my account in a way that everytime I create a new blank project those packages were already included, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably create a template with your packages listed.
A blank project is always blank and I doubt that you can change that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a single *project* that contains all the customisations you're after, including extra fonts, custom document classes and/or packages and possibly often-used images. Let's call this project `main`:

[image]

You can add whatever detail you want with comments and other bells and whistles. Then you can copy the project whenever you want to work on a new article:

[image]

Once you've created a copy, rename it and work on it.

[image]

This approach is slightly different from a *template*. The latter you'll have to maintain on GitHub or upload every time you want to use it, as this is the only option on using it in OverLeaf:

[image]